# alternative ways to blockwrite?

Tags: delphi

is there any alternate ways to blockwrite ?

now in my app i am using it like this

> BlockWrite(file, buffer[1],
>   Length(buffer));

i want to know alternate ways writing string to an exe file(binary )

just want to know different methods :)

can any one help me

thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard VCL solution is TFileStream class (TFileStream.Write and TFileStream.WriteBuffer methods).

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can stick to Windows API, by using [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858(VS.85).aspx), [WriteFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365747(VS.85).aspx), etc.